# Find overlapping letters in words

Tags: r, string, character, combinations, overlap

I have a string with only three words like this:

```
first_string <- c("self", "funny", "nymph")
```

As you can see the words of this vector can all be put together to one word because there is some overlap in letters, i.e. we get sel**f**un**ny**mph. Let`s call this a word train.

Besides, I have another vector with many words. Let the second vector be:

```
second_string <- c("house", "garden", "duck", "evil", "fluff")
```

I want to know what words of the second string can be added to the word train. In this case this is `house` and `fluff` (`house` can be added in the end of sel**f**un**ny**mph and `fluff` can be put between `self` and `funny`). So the expected output here would be:

```
expected <- data.frame(word= c("house", "fluff"), word_train= c("selfunnymphouse", "selfluffunnymph"))
```

The overlap can be of any length, i.e. self and funny overlap only with one character but funny and nymph overlap in two characters.

**EDIT**

The new word can change the word order of the first word train. For example, if the second vector contains the word `hugs` we can make the word train nymp**h**ug**s**el**f**unny, which puts `nymph` before `self` and `funny`.

Comment: So, you're not only looking for words from `second_string` which can be used *individually* to form a train with `first_string`, but also interested in combinations of words from `second_string` that together can be a train with `first_string`?

Comment: @CasparV. For my situation single words from second string that have a possible combination with all words of the first string is enough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm wondering why you asked this, but it was a fun exercise regardless. Here's my implementation:

```
library('dplyr')


# define cars -------------------------------------------------------------

original_cars <- c("self", "funny", "nymph")
new_cars <- c("house", "garden", "duck", "evil", "fluff")
cars <- c(original_cars, new_cars)


# get all possible connections ('parts') per car --------------------------

car_parts <- lapply(seq_along(cars), \(car_id) {
  
  car = cars[car_id]
  n = nchar(car)
  
  ids <- rep(car_id, n)
  names <- rep(car, n)
  left <- vapply(seq_len(n), \(i) substr(car, 1, i), "")
  right <- vapply(seq_len(n), \(i) substr(car, n-i+1, n), "")
  overlap <- nchar(left)
  
  data.frame(car.id = ids, car.name = names, left = left, right = right, overlap = overlap)
  
}) |> do.call(rbind, args=_)

# > car_parts
#    car.id car.name   left  right overlap
# 1       1     self      s      f       1
# 2       1     self     se     lf       2
# 3       1     self    sel    elf       3
# 4       1     self   self   self       4
# 5       2    funny      f      y       1
# 6       2    funny     fu     ny       2
# 7       2    funny    fun    nny       3
# 8       2    funny   funn   unny       4
# 9       2    funny  funny  funny       5
# 10      3    nymph      n      h       1
# [...]


# get all possible connections between two cars ---------------------------

connections <- inner_join(car_parts |> select(-left),
           car_parts |> select(-right),
           by = c('overlap', 'right' = 'left'),
           suffix = c('.left', '.right')) |>
  filter(car.id.left != car.id.right) |>
  mutate(connection.id = row_number()) |>
  select(connection.id, car.id.left, car.id.right, car.name.left, car.name.right, coupling = right)

rm(car_parts)

# > connections
#   connection.id car.id.left car.id.right car.name.left car.name.right coupling
# 1             1           1            2          self          funny        f
# 2             2           1            8          self          fluff        f
# 3             3           2            3         funny          nymph       ny
# 4             4           3            4         nymph          house        h
# 5             5           4            7         house           evil        e
# 6             6           4            1         house           self       se
# 7             7           5            3        garden          nymph        n
# 8             8           8            2         fluff          funny        f


# function to store valid trains ------------------------------------------

# example:
# valid_trains <- list()
# valid_trains <- add_valid_train( valid_trains, c(1, 8), c(2) )

add_valid_train <- function(valid_trains, train_cars, train_connections) {
  
  names = c(cars[train_cars[1]],
            vapply(train_connections, \(x) connections$car.name.right[x], "") )
  
  couplings = vapply(train_connections, \(x) connections$coupling[x], "")
  
  append(valid_trains, list(list(cars = train_cars, names = names, couplings = couplings)))
  
}


# function to recursively find next cars to add to train ------------------

# example:
# add_car(9, 5, c(1,2,3), c(1,3,5))

add_car <- function(valid_trains, new_car, new_connection = NULL, train_cars = c(), train_connections = c(), depth = 0) {
  
  cat(strrep('   ',depth), cars[new_car],'\n', sep='')
  
  # store current train as valid
  train_cars <- c(train_cars, new_car)
  train_connections <- c(train_connections, new_connection)
  
  # find next possible cars to add; save train if no more options, otherwise add all options
  options <- connections |> filter(car.id.left == new_car, ! car.id.right %in% train_cars)
  if(nrow(options) == 0) valid_trains <- add_valid_train(valid_trains, train_cars, train_connections) # save only the longest options
  for(i in seq_len(nrow(options))) valid_trains <- add_car(valid_trains, options$car.id.right[i], options$connection.id[i], train_cars, train_connections, depth+1)
  
  return(valid_trains)
  
}


# get all valid trains ----------------------------------------------------

valid_trains <- list()
for(i in seq_along(cars)) add_car(valid_trains, i) -> valid_trains

# filter valid trains that have all cars from `original_cars` -------------

mask <- vapply(valid_trains, \(x) all(seq_along(original_cars) %in% x$cars), T)

new_trains <- lapply(valid_trains[mask], \(x) {
  x$newcars <- setdiff(x$cars, seq_along(original_cars))
  x$newnames <- cars[x$newcars]
  x
})

# print names of all trains that contain all 'original' cars:
#
# > sapply(new_trains, \(x) x$names)
# [[1]] "self"  "funny" "nymph" "house" "evil" 
# [[2]] "self"  "fluff" "funny" "nymph" "house" "evil" 
# [[3]] "funny" "nymph" "house" "self"  "fluff"
# [[4]] "nymph" "house" "self"  "funny"
# [[5]] "nymph" "house" "self"  "fluff" "funny"
# [[6]] "house" "self"  "funny" "nymph"
# [[7]] "house" "self"  "fluff" "funny" "nymph"
# [[8]] "garden" "nymph"  "house"  "self"   "funny" 
# [[9]] "garden" "nymph"  "house"  "self"   "fluff"  "funny" 
# [[10]] "fluff" "funny" "nymph" "house" "self" 

## All possible trains are in `valid_trains`, all of those where *all* the original cars are used are in `new_trains`.
## 
## It is possible that some trains are subsets of others.
```

---

**edit:** When I looked at your own implementation, I thought you were interested in the longest possible trains. Now you explained the purpose, I adapted the algorithm to take the original cars, and see which of the new cars could be added *individually* to the original set. With the previous code, a long list of potential new names would have created some huge trains that would be very unfeasible for naming a family.

```
library('dplyr')


# define cars -------------------------------------------------------------

original_cars <- c("self", "funny", "nymph")
new_cars <- c("house", "garden", "duck", "evil", "fluff")


# function to get all possible connections between a set of cars ----------

# example:
# cars <- c("self", "funny", "nymph", "house")
# get_connections(cars)
#
# > get_connections(c("self", "funny", "nymph", "house"))
#   connection.id car.id.left car.id.right car.name.left car.name.right coupling
# 1             1           1            2          self          funny        f
# 2             2           2            3         funny          nymph       ny
# 3             3           3            4         nymph          house        h
# 4             4           4            1         house           self       se

get_connections <- function(cars) {
  
  # get all connections the cars can make
  car_parts <- lapply(seq_along(cars), \(car_id) {
    
    car = cars[car_id]
    n = nchar(car)
    
    ids <- rep(car_id, n)
    names <- rep(car, n)
    left <- vapply(seq_len(n), \(i) substr(car, 1, i), "")
    right <- vapply(seq_len(n), \(i) substr(car, n-i+1, n), "")
    overlap <- nchar(left)
    
    data.frame(car.id = ids, car.name = names, left = left, right = right, overlap = overlap)
    
  }) |> do.call(rbind, args=_)
  
  # > car_parts
  #    car.id car.name   left  right overlap
  # 1       1     self      s      f       1
  # 2       1     self     se     lf       2
  # 3       1     self    sel    elf       3
  # 4       1     self   self   self       4
  # 5       2    funny      f      y       1
  # 6       2    funny     fu     ny       2
  # [...]
  
  # return all possible connections between two cars
  
  inner_join(car_parts |> select(-left),
                            car_parts |> select(-right),
                            by = c('overlap', 'right' = 'left'),
                            suffix = c('.left', '.right')) |>
    filter(car.id.left != car.id.right) |>
    mutate(connection.id = row_number()) |>
    select(connection.id, car.id.left, car.id.right, car.name.left, car.name.right, coupling = right)
  
}


# function to store valid trains ------------------------------------------

# example:
# cars <- c("self", "funny", "nymph", "house")
# connections <- get_connections(cars)
# valid_trains <- list()
# valid_trains <- add_valid_train( cars, connections, valid_trains, c(2, 3), c(2) )

add_valid_train <- function(cars, connections, valid_trains, train_cars, train_connections) {
  
  names = c(cars[train_cars[1]],
            vapply(train_connections, \(x) connections$car.name.right[x], "") )
  
  couplings = vapply(train_connections, \(x) connections$coupling[x], "")
  
  append(valid_trains, list(list(cars = train_cars, names = names, couplings = couplings)))
  
}


# function to recursively find next cars to add to train ------------------

# example:
# cars <- c("self", "funny", "nymph", "house")
# connections <- get_connections(cars)
# valid_trains <- list()
# add_car(cars, connections, valid_trains, 2)

add_car <- function(cars, connections, valid_trains, new_car, new_connection = NULL, train_cars = c(), train_connections = c(), depth = 0) {
  
  cat(strrep('   ',depth), cars[new_car], '\n', sep='')
  
  # store current train as valid
  train_cars <- c(train_cars, new_car)
  train_connections <- c(train_connections, new_connection)
  
  # find next possible cars to add
  options <- connections |> filter(car.id.left == new_car, ! car.id.right %in% train_cars)
  for(i in seq_len(nrow(options))) valid_trains <- add_car(cars, connections, valid_trains, options$car.id.right[i], options$connection.id[i], train_cars, train_connections, depth+1)
  
  # save train if no more options
  if(nrow(options) == 0) valid_trains <- add_valid_train(cars, connections, valid_trains, train_cars, train_connections)
  
  return(valid_trains)
  
}


# find individual new cars that can be added to existing cars --------------

results <- lapply(new_cars, function(new_car) {
  
  cat('adding "',new_car,'":\n', sep='')
  cars <- c(original_cars, new_car)
  connections <- get_connections(cars)
  
  # get all possible trains
  valid_trains <- list()
  for(i in seq_along(cars)) add_car(cars, connections, valid_trains, i) -> valid_trains
  
  cat('\n')
  
  # return only trains where all cars are used
  valid_trains <- valid_trains[ sapply(valid_trains, \(x) length(x$cars)) == length(cars) ]
  return(list(new_car = new_car, options = length(valid_trains), trains = valid_trains))
})

for(result in results) {
  cat('\n', result$new_car, ': ', result$options, ' options ', sep='')
  for(train in result$trains) {
    cat('[',train$names,'] ')
  }
}
# detailed results are in `results`
```

```
house: 4 options [ self funny nymph house ] [ funny nymph house self ] [ nymph house self funny ] [ house self funny nymph ] 
garden: 0 options 
duck: 0 options 
evil: 0 options 
fluff: 1 options [ self fluff funny nymph ]
```

Comment: Will test later but looks promising! Thanks! "I'm wondering why you asked this": Actually a funny thing: Years ago we noticed that one can combine my name and the name of my wife to one word. Later we noticed that putting the name of our daughter in-between, we can still get a combined word which is like a family name of all of us. Now, my wife is pregnant and we are looking for a name which in combination with ours can be combined to one word. But of course it depends on the names that fit with ours whether we pick it or some other name.

Comment: @IgorstandswithUkraine That is a very nice thing to program for ❤️ Best wishes!

Comment: Just tried it with a database of 20k names and I am astonished to get 1431 names that in some way fit with ours (after adjusting the names phonologically). Thanks so much, will make a bounty for you!

Comment: @IgorstandswithUkraine That is very generous of you, thank you! I am very happy you appreciate the result

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be much harded than I thought but this is what I ended up doing:

- Make an matrix with the first n letters of each word and another matrix with last n letters of each word
- Comparing the two matrices shows which words overlap
- Paste overlaping words to a word train
- Repeating the steps above until there is no new overlap

Running the code for my data from question gave me such long word trains as I did not expect while writing the question, with the longest word trains being `gardenymphouselfluffunny` and `selfluffunnymphousevil` (both contain 6 words). The output data is:

```
                               wagons                    train
fluffunnymphouself       fluff, f....       fluffunnymphouself
funnymphouselfluff       funny, n....       funnymphouselfluff
gardenymphouselfluffunny garden, .... gardenymphouselfluffunny
gardenymphouselfunny     garden, ....     gardenymphouselfunny
houselfluffunnymph       house, s....       houselfluffunnymph
houselfunnymph           house, s....           houselfunnymph
selfluffunnymphousevil   fluff, f....   selfluffunnymphousevil
selfunnymphousevil       funny, n....       selfunnymphousevil
# The column wagons is a list of different length, depending on the words that are in the word train.
```

The code is quite long though..

```
# Vectors from question.
first_string <- c("self", "funny", "nymph")
second_string <- c("house", "garden", "duck", "evil", "fluff")

# Prepating the while loop which only runs while there are any new_wagons to add to the train.
all_wagons <- tolower(c(first_string, second_string))
new_wagons <- TRUE
results <- data.frame(wagons= I(list("")), train= "")

# Start the while loop.
while(any(new_wagons, na.rm= TRUE)){
# Going though every train that has been made so far..
  all_results <- by(results, list(results$train), function(train_i){
# What wagons have been used for this train?
    used_wagons <- unique(unlist(train_i[ , "wagons"]))
    used_wagons <- used_wagons[used_wagons != ""]
# What wagons can be used to extend the train?
    wagons_to_use_from <- unique(c(all_wagons[!all_wagons %in% used_wagons], train_i[ , "train"]))

# Get the first n letters of every word.
    wagon_start <- as.data.frame(sapply(wagons_to_use_from, function(wagon_i){
      sapply(1:max(nchar(wagons_to_use_from)), function(length_i){
        substr(wagon_i, 1, length_i)
      })}))
# Get the last n letters of every word.
    wagon_end <- as.data.frame(sapply(wagons_to_use_from, function(wagon_i){
      sapply(0:(max(nchar(wagons_to_use_from)-1)), function(length_i){
        substr(wagon_i, nchar(wagon_i)-length_i, nchar(wagon_i))
      })}))
# Find the overlap in letters.
    find_overlap <- data.frame(word= rep(names(wagon_end), each= nrow(wagon_end)))
    find_overlap$word_end <- unlist(wagon_end[ , unique(find_overlap$word)])
    find_overlap$without_word <- wagon_start[rep(1:nrow(wagon_start), ncol(wagon_end)), , drop= FALSE]
    find_overlap$without_word[matrix(c(1:nrow(find_overlap),
                                   rep(1:ncol(wagon_start), each= nrow(wagon_end))),
                                 ncol= 2)] <- NA
    new_wagons <- find_overlap$word_end == find_overlap$without_word

# If there is no new overlap then return the data as it was.
    if(!any(new_wagons, na.rm= TRUE)){
      results <- train_i
    } else{
# If there is an overlap then save the relevant words.
      word_i <- find_overlap$word[sort(which(new_wagons == TRUE, arr.ind = TRUE)[ , "row"])]
      word_overlap <- find_overlap$word_end[sort(which(new_wagons == TRUE, arr.ind = TRUE)[ , "row"])]
      word_after_i <- colnames(new_wagons)[which(t(new_wagons) == TRUE, arr.ind = TRUE)[, "row"]]
  
      word_trains <- data.frame(word_i, word_overlap, word_after_i, word_train= paste0(substr(word_i, 1, nchar(word_i)- nchar(word_overlap)),
                                                                                   word_after_i))
# Avoid former word trains as wagon names for next round:
      if(train_i$train != ""){
        word_trains <- word_trains[word_trains$word_i == train_i$train | word_trains$word_after_i == train_i$train, ]
      }
  # Output results where the former and new used words as well as the word train is.
      results <- do.call("rbind.data.frame", lapply(as.data.frame(t(word_trains)), function(word_trains_i){
        used_wagons_old <- used_wagons
        used_wagons_new <- c(word_trains_i[1], word_trains_i[3])
        wagons <- c(used_wagons_old, used_wagons_new)
        wagons <- wagons[wagons != train_i$train]
        wagons <- wagons[wagons != ""]
    
    
        data.frame(wagons= I(list(wagons)),
                   train= word_trains_i[4]
               
        )
    
      }))
    }


    list(results, new_wagons)

  })
# Make two dataframes, one with the word results, one with logicals whether there is any overlap.
  results <- do.call(rbind, lapply(all_results, `[[`, 1))
  results <- results[!duplicated(results$train), ]
  new_wagons <- unlist(do.call(list, lapply(all_results, `[[`, 2)))

}
```

Comment: I'm getting 8 results from this code, 2 of which incorrect: `[[7]] "fluff" "funny" "nymph" "house" "evil"  "self"` and 
`[[8]] "funny" "nymph" "house" "evil"  "self"`. And I miss a few that I found with my code: `"self"  "funny" "nymph" "house" "evil"`, `"self"  "fluff" "funny" "nymph" "house" "evil"`, `"nymph" "house" "self"  "funny"`, `"nymph" "house" "self"  "fluff" "funny"`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bulky/inefficient approach, due to `pracma::perms` for generating all permutations and checking the vadility of building trains, but I hope it could provide you with some clues

```
library(pracma)

# check if adjacent strings have overlaps
isOverlapped <- function(a, b) {
  for (k in 1:min(nchar(c(a, b)))) {
    if (substr(a, nchar(a) - k + 1, nchar(a)) == substr(b, 1, k)) {
      return(TRUE)
    }
  }
  FALSE
}

# check if a train can be created
checkTrain <- function(v) {
  for (i in 1:(length(v) - 1)) {
    if (!isOverlapped(v[i], v[i + 1])) {
      return(FALSE)
    }
  }
  TRUE
}

# produce all possible trains (based on first_string) with additional words from second_string
lapply(
  second_string ,
  function(x) {
    lst <- asplit(perms(c(first_string, x)), 1)
    lst[sapply(lst,checkTrain)]
  }
)
```

and you will obtain a list

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "house" "self"  "funny" "nymph"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "nymph" "house" "self"  "funny"

[[1]][[3]]
[1] "funny" "nymph" "house" "self"

[[1]][[4]]
[1] "self"  "funny" "nymph" "house"


[[2]]
list()

[[3]]
list()

[[4]]
list()

[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] "self"  "fluff" "funny" "nymph"
```

where `house` gives `4` possible trains and `fluff` gives `1` train, while other words in `second_string` cannot contribute to building any trains based on `first_string`.